# Bottom Overflow dateTimePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

Okay. So I've created a TextField where in the user is required to select date of birth. Everything works fine. User clicks the field > calendar shows up > User selects the date and it is done.

However the issue starts when if the user clicks "Edit Date" after the calendar is opened. Though, there is enough space, I still get a bottom overflow error.

[image: When date Picker opens]

> This happens when the button in highlighted in Picture 1 is clicked :

[image: When we click edit button present in picture 1]

This is how the code looks :

```
Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: DimensionConstants.margin8,
                          left: DimensionConstants.margin16,
                          right: DimensionConstants.margin16),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller:
                            _dobController, 
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              gapPadding: 0,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 0,
                                horizontal: DimensionConstants.margin16),
                            suffixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                              size: 20.0,
                              color: HexColor(ColorConstants.blue),
                            ),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              gapPadding: 0,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              gapPadding: 0,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                              
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              gapPadding: 0,
                         BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: HexColor(
                                ColorConstants.whiteSmoke), 
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never),

                        readOnly:
                            true, 
                        onTap: () async {
                          DateTime age16plusDate = DateTime(
                              DateTime.now().year - 16,
                              DateTime.now().month,
                              DateTime.now().day);
                          DateTime pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                                return Theme(
                                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                                    primaryColor: Colors.black,
                                    accentColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
                                    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                                        primary: const Color(0xFF000000)),
                                  ),
                                  child: child,
                                );
                              },
                              context: context,
                              initialDate: age16plusDate,
                              firstDate: DateTime(1947),
                              lastDate: age16plusDate,
                              fieldLabelText: 'Date of Birth',
                              fieldHintText: 'MONTH/DATE/YEAR',
                              initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day);

                          if (pickedDate != null) {
                            print(
                                pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                            String formattedDate =
                                DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);

                            setState(() {
                              _dobController.text =
                                  formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
                            });
                          } else {
                            print("Date is not selected");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i looked for "_datePickerHeaderPortraiHeight" then changed value inside date_picker.dart to fixing my problem.
You can try looking for this line and change `static const double _datePickerHeaderPortraitHeight = 120.0;`